# Macro for auto row height in document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a very large document with multiple tables, and I would like a macro that would set the row height automatically for each table in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will change the height of every rows in every table to size 100.

```
Sub tablechanger()

Dim tableid As Tables

Set tableid = ActiveDocument.Tables

For Each tb In tableid

For Each rw In tb.Rows

rw.Height = 100

Next rw

Next tb

End Sub
```